# Boot Remix OS automatically (syslinux.cfg)

Tags: syslinux

I am wondering how I can boot the Resident Mode of Remix OS automatically without having to select it at each boot? I read in a couple articles to do `default -live` but what option will it select? How do I make it select it?

```
default menu.c32
prompt 0
menu title Remix OS
timeout 0


label ubnentry0
menu label ^Resident mode - All your data and apps are saved
kernel /kernel
append initrd=/initrd.img root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=remix_x86_64 androidboot.selinux=permissive quiet SRC= DATA= CREATE_DATA_IMG=1

label ubnentry1
menu label ^Guest mode - No data will be saved after each session
kernel /kernel
append initrd=/initrd.img root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=remix_x86_64 androidboot.selinux=permissive quiet SRC= DATA= DATA_IN_MEM=1
```

Would I use something like `default -ubnentry0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did, and it works!

```
default ubnentry0


label ubnentry0
menu label ^Resident mode - All your data and apps are saved
kernel /kernel
append initrd=/initrd.img root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=remix_x86 androidboot.selinux=permissive quiet SRC= DATA= USB_DATA_PARTITION=1
```